# How to fix fail of Explorer Search on network drive?

Tags: windows-7

On Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, this file on a Win XP SP3 network drive "S:"

[image]

should be found by this search:

[image]

EDIT: esp. since an equivalent search on C: succeeds:

[image]

EDIT: Local C: is indexed. Network S: is not. Both have '[x] Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties'.

How can I fix the failure?

Answer (score 1):

The search box by default does a search on the file name and you are looking for a match in a title property. Add `title:` before the text to filter the search on title.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that workaround works here, but since it is unnecessary  on e.g. C: (see addition to question) shouldn't it be unnecessary on S: too?

Comment: Is your local drive indexed? That may be why it automatically includes the other fields in the search. Probably for performance reasons on the network drive it is just doing the simple file name search.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: I see that "sleep" exists in both the file name and title. Have you tried a file on the local drive with the word only in the title, as is the case with the file on your shared drive? Also, as Brad says indexing might well be a factor in this.

Comment: Brad, yes the local drive is indexed. The network drive is not. I see nothing in the user docs to suggest the index is required for anything except speed. Karan, yes I have tried the local drive with a word in only the title (I've updated the screenshot accordingly) - no change.